# Proof of the Cayley Transform. Showing that $H=i(I-U)(I+U)^{-1}$ where $U=(I+iH)(I-iH)^{-1}$ for a Hermitian matrix $H$.

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I am working on showing that  a Hermitian matrix $H=i(I-U)(I+U)^{-1}$ where $U=(I+iH)(I-iH)^{-1}$.

I have already shown that $I-iH$ is invertible and that $U$ is unitary, but am stuck on showing that $U$ can be written in this form. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you so much!

Comment: If not that's the definition of $U$ then what? Or is your problem at showing that these operations are inverses of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with $U=(I+iH)(I-iH)^{-1}$, and you want to find $H$ in terms of $U$, start by multiplying by sides on the right by $I-iH$:
$$
               U(I-iH)=(I+iH) \\
               U-iUH = I+iH \\
               U-I = i(U+I)H \\
               -i(U-I)(U+I)^{-1}=H\\
               H=i(I-U)(I+U)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lena : You are most welcome.